# Get dataset to work with datatables ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, json, linq, datatables

I have a class like so:

```
public class Group
{
     public int RecID { get; set; }
     public int GroupID { get; set; }
     public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I get an IList of these items: `IList<Group>()`;

Now I'm trying to return a javascript array of this list so that I can use it with [jquery datatables](https://www.datatables.net)

So i tried the following in my controller:

```
return Json(CacheHelper.Groups, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But this gives me the following result:

```
[
    {"GroupID":"1","Name":"Group 1","RecID":5637144589},
    {"GroupID":"2","Name":"Group 2","RecID":5637145326}
]
```

How do I get this to work with datatables?

I have tried things like:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": '/ajax/data.json'
    "columns": [
        "Name",
        "GroupID",
        "RecID"
    ]
} );
```

But this fails to load the data.  I thought it may be because the data is in the wrong json format as it is expecting data like

**Expected data format**

```
{
    data: [
        1,
        "Group 1",
        5637144589
    ],
    [
        2,
        "Group 2",
        5637145326
    ]
}
```

So I tried the following linq to change the data:

```
 CacheHelper.Groups.Select(x => new string[] { x.GroupID, x.Name, x.RecID });
```

but this gives me an array of arrays, without the `data` bit.

```
[
    ["1","Group 1",5637144589],
    ["2","Group 2",5637145326]
]
```

Is there any way to get the data bit in with linq?

**So I guess the question is**

- Is there any way to use the first json result dataset and get it to work with js

if not

- is there any way to use linq to make the dataset look like the expected data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following initialization code to match your data structure:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "ajax": {
       "url": '/ajax/data.json',
       "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data" : "Name" },
        { "data" : "GroupID" },
        { "data" : "RecID" }
    ]
});
```

From the [dataSrc](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) property description:

> Note that if your Ajax source simply returns an array of data to
>   display, rather than an object, set this parameter to be an empty
>   string.

Comment: Wow, so simple when you know how!